# How to tell ld where to find libc

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, clang, opensuse

So I created a static library with some basic assistance functions in C++ today. I built it with Clang 3.2 (SVN snapshot). However when I try to run a test program that links to it (prog.cpp), I get the following error:

```
~/Projects/CPP/AssisterLib> g++ prog.cpp -o program -static -L. -lassister
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.6/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -lm
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.6/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I get the same error with G++ and Clang++. Apparently it can't find libc.a and libm.a, which are both in /usr/lib64 (provided by glibc-devel in OpenSUSE). Adding `-L/usr/lib64` does nothing for the error.

Why can't ld find those libraries? Is there a flag that I'm missing?

Comment: try adding `-Wl,--verbose`, this will tell linker show its attempts to find library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is likely the use of `-static`. I would conclude you do not have static version of the `libm` and `libc` installed. You can try removing `-static` to confirm.

The `-static` flag signals to the compiler that you want your executable to be entirely statically linked, and so it fails if not all the libraries have static versions available.

Comment: Removing static makes it work, but the compile still fails with several undefined references. All of them are to a class defined in my library. Here's the pastebin link: [link](http://pastebin.com/zbQGUU9s)

Comment: @PrinceBilliard: In your question, you were using `g++` to build, but in the pastbin, you are using `clang++`. What happens with `g++`?

Comment: The same thing. AFAIK Clang uses the GNU linker. In any case, the error messages are exactly the same.

Comment: @PrinceBilliard: I think you must not have included the `.o` file for the `ArgumentException` code in your library, or it is in a different library that you are not linking in.

Comment: Everything's in the same library. One header, one CPP file. Compiled to one lib. And the library compiled with no errors or warnings (with -Wall). Would the code help?

Comment: @PrinceBilliard: Sure, let's have a look. Another pastebin?

Comment: Code is here: [library code](http://pastebin.com/rSbJZZ5C) and [header](http://pastebin.com/hSDUEBfk)

Comment: @PrinceBilliard: You are missing the implementation of your destructor for `ArgumentException`. Regards

Comment: Ah! Of course. I didn't even think of it; since it would be blank anyway. I'm surprised Clang didn't even warn of that. Thank you for your assistance. And you were right about the -static flag too, so your answer is accepted. Thank you again.